Logout from Microsoft Azure Account when it is used in AWS Cognito
I've integrated Cognito OAuth in my asp.net 4.5, which includes the option to sign in with a Microsoft Azure account. Although I've utilized the logout method provided by Cognito, signing out from the Microsoft account doesn't occur. I aim for complete sign-out, prompting the user to enter their credentials again.
enter image description here
Image shows the hosted UI provided by Cognito, First time when I click on Microsoft option it asks for the credentials and take to my app but when logout from the app and click on it again, it does ask for credentials and take me straight to my app.
I want to logout from the Microsoft Account too.
I have tried this
string microsoftLogoutUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/3ff5e1f8-1e10-4ab0-a9f0-0e2973df3ff3/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={Uri.EscapeDataString(redirect_uri)}";

but it does not take us back to out application after logging out from the Microsoft account.

To completely sign out the user from their Microsoft Azure account when using AWS Cognito, you need to redirect the user to the Microsoft identity platform logout endpoint. string microsoftLogoutUri = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri={Uri.EscapeDataString(redirectUri)}";
